# null Lagrange multiplier

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I used the KKT conditions to solve a convex optimization problem with 5 inequality constraints and 3 variables. I found 4 null Lagrangian multipliers and one non-null, function of one variable.

- How to interpret this situation?
- how to get the other 2 variables? Can I suppose equality for the other constraints.

Comment: Generally a null multiplier indicates that the associated local optimum is strictly internal to the feasible region.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective function is $\ f(x,y)\ $, non-null Lagrange multiplier is $\ \lambda\ $, and constraint corresponding to $\ \lambda $ is $\ g(x,y)\ge 0\ $, then you should have $3$ equations
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) - \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)&=0\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) - \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)&=0\\
g(x,y)&= 0
\end{align}
to solve for the values of the three variables $\ x, y\ $, and $\ \lambda \ $ in an optimal solution.